# NSDictionary recursive loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm using the following function in order to get all the keys and values of the preferences.plist file located in: `/private/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

```
- (void)FindKeysAndValuesInPlist:(id)object forKeyNamed:(NSString *)keyName{
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
      NSLog(@"%@",keyName);
    [object enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
        [self FindKeysAndValuesInPlist:value forKeyNamed:key];
    }];

}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    [object enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [self FindKeysAndValuesInPlist:obj forKeyNamed:nil];
    }];
}
else
{

    NSLog(@"%@.%@", keyName, object);
}   
}
```

An example of the content of preferences.plist:

```
{
CurrentSet = "/Sets/3B9E7BEB-5558-4497-803B-21B03E6A46C0";
NetworkServices =     {
    "014226AB-75B7-41CF-9B96-48E82FD6A395" =         {
        Interface =             {
            DeviceName = ip4;
            Hardware = "com.apple.CommCenter";
            Type = "com.apple.CommCenter";
            UserDefinedName = "com.apple.CommCenter (ip4)";
        };
        PrimaryRank = Never;
        UserDefinedName = "com.apple.CommCenter (ip4)";
        "com.apple.CommCenter" =             {
            AllowNetworkAccess = 0;
            Available = 1;
            Version = 11;
        };
    };
    "1C01B561-1A55-4E3B-82FC-CDFF5024F0D2" =         {
        Interface =             {
            DeviceName = ip1;
            Hardware = "com.apple.CommCenter";
            Type = "com.apple.CommCenter";
            UserDefinedName = "com.apple.CommCenter (ip1)";
        };
        UserDefinedName = "com.apple.CommCenter (ip1)";
        "com.apple.CommCenter" =             {
            AllowNetworkAccess = 1;
            Available = 1;
            SettingsHaveBeenAlteredByPreferences = 1;
            Setup =                 {
                apn = "";
                password = "";
                signature = <7ecb277c ad546563 3ac057fb db40aeaa 939f8c0e e7ae68c2 6e0ff602 77d3868d 18a63059 6c83f66d 46b8af57 d1bf83d0 2655ced6 57d773f4 5c7e733e 923aaa07 39165357 a4ecf270 130276f0 59c7470e 0b61a631 dff04fd1 0bc80cb4 a0dc0a03 96a8ebf0 74c24cdb 84c38239 9f6f7f05 ee032982 8ed1b72d b531405b 09e35f5b>;
                "type-mask" = 0;
                username = "";
            };
            Version = 11;
        };
    };
```

The problem is that I'm trying to create this kind of output format: MAINKEY.SUBKEY.VALUE

For example:

```
NetworkServices =     {
"014226AB-75B7-41CF-9B96-48E82FD6A395" =         {
    Interface =             {
        DeviceName = ip4;
        Hardware = "com.apple.CommCenter";
        Type = "com.apple.CommCenter";
        UserDefinedName = "com.apple.CommCenter (ip4)";
    };
```

Would be: NetworkServices.014226AB-75B7-41CF-9B96-48E82FD6A395.Interface.Hardware.ip4

Comment: "The problem is that I'm trying to create this kind of output format: MAINKEY.SUBKEY.VALUE" - that's not a problem. The problem is that - I assume - it doesn't work. Where's the code that generates the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the keys in a dictionary. When the value for a key is another dictionary, push the key onto a stack and recurse on the dictionary value. When the value is a string or number, then concatenate the keys in the stack and print the key path and value.

Code:

```
+ (void)printDict:(NSDictionary *)dict keyStack:(NSArray *)keys
{
    if (keys == nil) {
        keys = [NSArray array];
    }

    for (id key in dict) {
        id value = dict[key];
        if ([value respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
            [self printDict:value keyStack:[keys arrayByAddingObject:key]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ = %@", [[keys arrayByAddingObject:key] componentsJoinedByString:@"."], value);
        }
    }
}
```